# Loading and playing music in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So i'm trying to play music on pygame and so far I can successfully load and play the music on the program, but I can do that without variables and i'm not sure how to do it with variables involved.

I've already tried to store them inside a variable and playing them from the variable.

```
Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.load("MainMenu.mp3")
Menumusic.play(-1, 0.0)
```

I expect the music to play but instead i get this as the output:

```
Menumusic.play(-1, 0.0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should call pygame.mixer.music.play() to start playback of the loaded music stream.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you mean by *playing from a variable* but it seems to me that you want to change what music is played. You can't do without your variable `Menumusic` because it contains all the functionality needed to play the music.

```
myvariablemp3 = "MainMenu.mp3"   # Change this to some way of varying the filename 
Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.load(myvariablemp3)
Menumusic.play(-1, 0.0)
```

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness but yeah that was the structure I tried to also use but it just outputted "nonetype has no attribute play"

Comment: I'm doing this so that later on in the code when I need to the music to stop playing, I could just say "Menumusic.stop()" instead of writing out "pygame.mixer.music...."

Comment: If you got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'` that is because your call to `pygame.mixer.music.load` failed (problem with filename or path, maybe?) and not because what your code was doing was wrong. If you do it correctly there is no difference whatsoever between calling `load` with a literal string and calling `load` with a variable that contains a string.

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with the path or the file name and i'm not sure why this is even happening

Comment: I still say that your call to `pygame.mixer.music.load` is failing, and so *something* about that call is wrong. Please edit your question to show us (1) the code that assigns the filename to a variable (2) the call your code makes to `pygame.mixer.music.load` with that variable and (3) the complete error message including the traceback that you get when your code does the call. At the moment your question only shows a redacted version of the problem describing what you think is wrong but not showing us exactly what, where and how it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to hold a sound in a variable, the code needs to use `pygame.mixer.Sound()` to load the file in.

For example:

```
drum_beat = pygame.mixer.Sound("bass_drum.wav")
```

Later on in the code, the pre-loaded sound can be played by passing the *result* from that `.Sound(...)` call (in this case `drum_beat`) to `pygame.mixer.Sound.play()`.

```
drum_beat = pygame.mixer.Sound("bass_drum.wav")
...
pygame.mixer.Sound.play( drum_beat )
```